# Create a list with following numbers (recursive)

Tags: java, list, recursion, nodes

I need the function to return a  list with following numbers so `follow(null, 5);` should return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

I tried this:

```
public static Node <Integer> follow(Node<Integer>list, int num)
{
    if(num==1)
        return new Node<Integer>(1);
    return new Node<Integer>(num, follow(list, num-1));
}
```

but this returns `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` instead of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` what do I need to change in the function so it will return `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? (I dont want to add another functions)

This is the Node Class:

```
package unit4.collectionsLib;

public class Node<T>
{
    private T info;
    private Node<T> next;

    public Node(T x)
    {
        this.info = x;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(T x, Node<T> next)
    {
        this.info = x;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public T getValue()
    {
        return(this.info);
    }



}
```

Comment: You don't need our help for this, you have all the information you need already. Look at your code: why would it be putting lower numbers to the right, instead of left, of higher numbers? (take a pencil and some paper, and literally write out what happens at every single step when you start with num=2)

Comment: What is the constructor for `Node`?

Comment: To add to Mike's comment: the issue is with the order of your recursion.

Comment: I cant understand how to order it this is confusing.

Comment: you can still work with the same implementation then reverse it's order, if it is an array.

Comment: @n0thing It's a custom linked list, not an array.

Comment: @yoav I suggest that you learn about tail recursion to help you solve this problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice if I use tail recursion will I need to add another variable?

Comment: @yoav No, you won't need any new variables. You just need to change your `return` statements as I hint at in my answer. Please take some time to try to answer the two questions I ask there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I cant think of the solution I really tried.

Comment: @yoav Start with the base case. Instead of creating a node with `1` as the end of the list, you need to create a node with `1` and then the rest of the list. Which `Node` constructor should you use to do this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `new Node<Integer>(1, next)`

Comment: @yoav Exactly. And what can you pass for `next`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `follow(list, num-1)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203206/discussion-between-yoav-and-code-apprentice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Node <Integer> follow(Node<Integer>list, int num)
{
    if(num==1)
        return new Node<Integer>(1);
```

In your base case, you are creating a node with the smallest number. How can you change this to put the smallest number at the front of the list?

```
    return new Node<Integer>(num, follow(list, num-1));
```

In the recursive case, you are adding the current number at the front of the list. How can you change this to add the current number at the end?

```
}
```

Comment: So how would you add the current number to the end of the list? That's the crux of the question. As is done often in list-processing, the list is defined as a single-element head and a tail that is in itself a list. It's not trivial to add a single element to the end of a list this way in a recursive manner.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt "So how would you add the current number to the end of the list?" The solution is to switch around the nesting of the recursive call to `follow()` and the creation of a `new Node()`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Maybe my wording is poorly chosen. I guess you don't really "add the current number to the end of the list". Instead you add it in front of the `list` parameter passed in rather than in front of the return from a recursive call to `follow()`.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In pseudocode it is the difference between building `follow(follow(follow(3)), 2), 1)` vs `follow(follow(follow(1), 2), 3)`.

Comment: That means that you have a list as the head and a single item as the tail. There are very few algorithms that work with that (actually, effectively you have just said "iterate through the list in reverse order" because changing the order of the constructor arguments doesn't change the data structure). And it's very inefficient to traverse a head|tail list backward as it requires recursion to even the first element.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I dont understand the solution can you please write it?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt "That means that you have a list as the head and a single item as the tail." That depends on the `Node` class itself and its constructor, not the `follow()` algorithm. I have a working solution on repl.com, but am hesitant to post it here since I don't feel like doing someone's homework for them.

Comment: @yoav Think about the two questions I wrote in my answer here. How can you modify the base case so that the `1` is placed at the beginning of the `list` instead of at the end?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Specifically, we can use [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) for an elegant solution that only modifies the two `return` statements from the original code in the question. Not only will the code remain as 5 lines, but most modern compilers can optimize out the recursive calls.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt One way to think of this is that you need to build the list as you call `follow()` recursively rather than as you return from each call as the OP is doing.

Answer (score 1):

You're counting down from 5 to 1 as you go deeper into recursion. What if you counted up from 1 to 5 as you went deeper into the recursion? What would the order be of the numbers?

To implement that, the maximum number (5 in your example) needs to be available at every recursion step, so you need an extra argument for that.

```
public static Node <Integer> follow(Node<Integer>list, int num, int max)
{
    if(num==max)
        return new Node<Integer>(max);
    return new Node<Integer>(num, follow(list, num + 1, max));
}
```

If you still want to have the convenience available of calling without passing the extra argument, you can overload the method by adding a convenience version of it:

```
public static Node <Integer> follow(Node<Integer>list, int max)
{
    return follow(list, 1, max);
}
```

Comment: This solution changes the signature of the function. There is a tail-recursive solution that leaves the signature the same. (And the compiler might be able to optimize out the recursion.)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It doesn't change the signature of the function if you add the overloaded method. You can even make the first method private. It's a very common way of doing recursion - because the recursive step may need extra parameters (accumulators, as in this case, or collectors, that are not present on the public method)

Comment: Yes, this is a common tool for recursion. In this particular case, it is unnecessary. The return statements in the original code can be modified to get the desired behavior without introducing a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Given the limitation you commented, you could start with a node set to 1 and count up.

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Question {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Node<Integer> list = new Node<Integer>(1);
        list.setNext(follow(list, 5));
        print(list);
    }

    public static Node <Integer> follow(Node<Integer>list, int num)
    {
        if(list.getValue() == num)
            return null;

        Node<Integer> nextNode = new Node<Integer>(list.getValue()+1);
        nextNode.setNext(follow(nextNode, num));
        return nextNode;
    }

    public static void print(Node<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println(list.getValue());
        if (list.next == null) {
            return;
        }

        print(list.next);
    }

    public static class Node<T>
    {
        private T info;
        private Node<T> next;

        public Node(T x)
        {
            this.info = x;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public Node(T x, Node<T> next)
        {
            this.info = x;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public T getValue()
        {
            return(this.info);
        }

        public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Not the cleanest solution, but given what's being asked you could calculate the info field in the follow method.  I used a class variable `max` to know how large the list needs to be

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Question {
    static int max = 5;
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Node<Integer> list = follow(null, max);
        print(list);
    }

    public static Node <Integer> follow(Node<Integer>list, int num)
    {
        int calculatedInfo = max - (num - 1);
        if(calculatedInfo == max)
            return new Node<Integer>(max);
        return new Node<Integer>(calculatedInfo, follow(list, num-1));
    }

    public static void print(Node<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println(list.info);
        if (list.next == null) {
            return;
        }

        print(list.next);
    }

    public static class Node<T>
    {
        private T info;
        private Node<T> next;

        public Node(T x)
        {
            this.info = x;
            this.next = null;
        }

        public Node(T x, Node<T> next)
        {
            this.info = x;
            this.next = next;
        }

        public T getValue()
        {
            return(this.info);
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

**RESULT MAX = 10**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: The function needs to work with num and list and no more variables.

Comment: @yoav Edit your question and explain what your requirements are.  Your comment is not mentioned in your question as a limitation.

Comment: I am not sure this solution is recursive because you must call the function with the max variable.

Comment: @yoav The code calls follow within follow, how is that not recursion?  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Node <Integer> follow(Node<Integer>list, int num)
{
    if(num==1)
        return new Node<Integer>(num, list);
    return follow(new Node<Integer>(num, list), num-1);
}
```

This returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`